# css on share button

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble isolating the problem I'm having, some stray CSS. Here's my website: http://www.derekbeck.com/1775/info/july2012mag/

Can anyone tell me what CSS is causing the Share button, when you mouseover it, to pop up off on the right side instead of directly next to the share button?

Thanks,
Derek

Comment: Which `css` and `javascript` files you use for these social buttons? Please, give us a direction, at least.

Comment: in firefox it is showing okay..but in chrome it is showing the wrong.

Comment: I'm uncertain if I ought to downvote this question. The question itself seems fine; the issue I'm having is that your question relies on an external site. If ever you change your homepage, this question might suddenly no longer make sense. It would be nice if you attempted to extract only the relevant HTML & CSS bits of your website and re-posted them here, so that there's no danger of context being lost later.

Comment: Thanks for the note, I will do better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `position:relative` under `#addthis` in your CSS file:

```
#addthis
{
    position:relative;
    top:-2px;
    left:2px;
}
```

Should be:

```
#addthis
{
    top:-2px;
    left:2px;
}
```

### Edit:

BTW, I'd suggest you put all your CSS code into a single, separate file.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this! On the single CSS: it is part of the mess that comes with Wordpress and plugins, each having its own CSS, etc. I'm not sure I can easily put them into one file.